# Inequalities in a paper of J.Bourgain

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities

I am reading a paper 'Periodic Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation and Invariant Measures' written by J.Bourgain. And I am wondering if I can have some help from this website.

At (2.13) of the paper, there is a sequence of inequalities as below.

\begin{align*}
\left\|  \sum_n \int_{|\lambda+n^2|>1} d\lambda \frac{\widehat{\Gamma(u)}(n,\lambda)}{\lambda+n^2}e^{i(nx+\lambda t)}    \right\|_{L^4(\pi\times [0,1])} 
&\leq C\left( \sum_n \int d\lambda \frac{\left| \widehat{\Gamma(u)}(n,\lambda) \right|^2}{1+|\lambda+n^2|^{\frac{5}{4}}}  \right)^{1/2}\\ 
&\leq  C\left( \sum_n \int d\lambda \frac{\left| \widehat{\Gamma(u)}(n,\lambda) \right|^2}{1+|\lambda+n^2|^{\frac{3}{4}}}  \right)^{1/2}\\ 
&\leq C\| \Gamma(u)  \|_{L^{\frac{4}{3}}(\pi\times [0,1])} 
\end{align*}

Where $\pi=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

The second inequality is easy. **I have question on first and last inequalities.**

As for last inequality, I have no idea.... :(

As for first inequality, it feels like it is typo or something.. because, in order to have that inequality, we should have

$$ \frac{\left(1+|\lambda+n^2|\right)^{3/4}}{(\lambda+n^2)^2} \leq \frac{1}{1+|\lambda+n^2|^{5/4}}  $$

Here, I have used inequality given in (2.6) of the paper given below.

$$ \left\| \sum_n \int d\lambda a(n,\lambda) e^{i(nx+\lambda t)}  \right\|_{L^4} \leq C\left( \sum_n \int d\lambda (1+|\lambda +n^2|)^{3/4} |a(n,\lambda)|^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}  $$

Then, setting $|\lambda + n^2|=2$, with some further computation, we obtain
$$3^7\leq 2^8$$
which is nonsense...  I hope to know where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The inequality is true, with a constant $C$ : you are asking if $$ \frac{(1+x)^{3/4}}{x^2}\leq \frac{C}{1+x^{5/4}}$$ for all $x\geq1$, where the constant $C$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: @username Thank you for your answer.  That makes sense! Then I should think that the constant C is changing at every inequality.

Comment: @username  If it is not too much, can I ask your opinion on the third inequality?